# How to use external colormaps (ex plotly) in matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I am working on some data visualization, and noticed that the python library was quite lacking in cyclic colormaps. After some searching around, I saw that plotly offered some good options! However, I am having trouble implementing it into my code. I have definitely installed it correctly (when I print a list of their swatches it works), but can't actually get it to work on my graph. Here's the code! Any help would be appreciated!

```
import plotly.express as px
wd = merge_all_jan['Wind Dir (10s deg)']
conc = merge_all_jan['Mean_CO2']
ws = merge_all_jan['Wind Spd (km/h)']

cmap = px.colors.cyclical.mrybm


plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.scatter(ws, conc, c=wd, s = 20, marker='o', cmap = cmap)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor('white')
cbar = plt.colorbar(pad=0.1)
cbar.set_label('Wind Direction (Deg.)',rotation=270, labelpad = 10)
plt.ylabel("CO₂ (ppm)")
plt.xlabel("Wind Speed (km/h)")
plt.title("Asymptotic CO₂ concentration by wind speed")
```

I've tried a few different ways of changing the cmap variable but none have worked for me.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What color do you want to assign to which point?

Comment: I'm trying to have a continuous colour map for my data (ie have the colour change based on the value as assigned with c = wd, cmap = cmap, where cmap = the colour gradient)

Comment: Have you checked this documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html ?

Comment: Yep! I've looked through it, twilight is a decent option but I'm looking to have more options in terms of cyclic colormaps.

Comment: What is your current output? What do you want to change? If you want a cyclic colormap, well you can always append any reversed colormap at the end of the original colormap, you'll have a cyclic colormap!

Comment: That's an interesting idea! I'll definitely try that.